# Pact Test -consumer connection refused error

Tags: pact

I am trying to run the pact contract test on consumer side to generate the pact contract. But always getting a connection refused error.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE, properties = 
"product-service.products.baseUrl:http://localhost:9001/svc-product-service/api/products")
public class ProductServiceContractTest {
@Autowired
private ProductService productService;

@Rule
public PactProviderRuleMk2 provider = new PactProviderRuleMk2("svc-product-service", "localhost", 9001, this);

@Pact(consumer = "svc-product-order-service")
public RequestResponsePact pactProductExists(PactDslWithProvider builder) {
    return builder.given("Product 1001 exists").uponReceiving("A request to /1001").path("/1001").method("GET")
            .willRespondWith().status(200)
            .body(new PactDslJsonBody().integerType("id", 1001).stringType("name", "Laptop"))
            .toPact();
}

@PactVerification(fragment = "pactProductExists")
@Test
public void productExists() {
    final Product product = productService.fetchProductsById(1001);
    assertThat(product.getId()).isEqualTo(1001);
    assertThat(product.getName()).isEqualTo("Laptop");

}

}
```

POM dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
   <artifactId>pact-jvm-consumer-java8_2.12</artifactId>
   <version>3.5.24</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Stack trace:

[ERROR] com.example.product.order.service.ProductServiceContractTest.productExists  Time elapsed: 0.034 s  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:9001/svc-product-service/api/products/1001": Connect to localhost:9001 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9001 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
at com.example.product.order.service.ProductServiceContractTest.productExists(ProductServiceContractTest.java:79)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9001 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
at com.example.product.order.service.ProductServiceContractTest.productExists(ProductServiceContractTest.java:79)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at com.example.product.order.service.ProductServiceContractTest.productExists(ProductServiceContractTest.java:79)